# Replace last comma with or using ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

What is the best way to convert an array of values in ColdFusion

```
[ Fed Jones, John Smith, George King, Wilma Abby]
```

and to a list where the last comma is an or

```
Fed Jones, John Smith, George King or Wilma Abby
```

I thought REReplace might work but haven't found the right expression yet.

Comment: reReplace might work but the answer provided by @Henry is much more readable.  That's important if you ever have to modify it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you've got an array, combining the last element with an ArrayToList is the simplest way (as per [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830713/replace-last-comma-with-or-using-coldfusion/9360)).

If you've got it as a string, using rereplace is a valid method, and would work like so:

```
<cfset Names = rereplace( Names , ',(?=[^,]+$)' , ' or ' ) />
```

Which says match a comma, then check (without matching) that there are no more commas until the end of the string (which of course will only apply for the last comma, and it will thus be replaced).

Comment: +1 as it properly handles single element (or even empty) lists out of the box.

Comment: Peter's DNA is made out of regex.  I've seen it.

Comment: @Travis - Rofl. I would not be at all surprised if that turned out to be true :)

Comment: Hah, _I wish!_    (I really do; if there's any genies around, I have this lovely lamp to trade...)

Comment: Uh oh, I think I saw a Twilight Zone episode that started like this .. ;)

Comment: I would say this is a better solution even when dealing with arrays. Just `arrayToList()` and do the regex replace without the need for any array manipulation. Of course it's a different story if you're dealing with "Surname, First name" types of arrays, i.e. `["Jones, Fed", "Smith, John", "King, George", "Abby, Wilma"]`

Comment: @Ketola - True, but in that case you would normally use a different delimiter with `arrayToList`. One that is not contained in the data itself.

Comment: @Leigh - Obviously true as well. What _was_ I thinking. =)

Comment: Thanks. I like the simplicity of being able to accomplish this in only one line.

Comment: You could use negative lookahead as well: `,(?!.*,)` instead of `,(?=[^,]+$)`

Comment: You could also clap your hands ten times before every keypress, but it'd be an awfully inefficient way of typing.

Answer (score 5):

It'd be easier to manipulate in the array level first, before converting into a list.

```
names = ["Fed Jones", "John Smith", "George King", "Wilma Abby"];
lastIndex = arrayLen(names);
last = names[lastIndex];
arrayDeleteAt(names, lastIndex);
result = arrayToList(names, ", ") & " or " & last;  
// result == "Fed Jones, John Smith, George King or Wilma Abby"
```

Comment: compliments on the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: If the array length is variable, be sure to adjust the code to anticipate single element arrays or empty arrays to avoid errors or repeated values ie `"Fed Jones or Fed Jones"`.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to work with a list / string using listLast and the JAVA [lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method of the result string.

```
<cfscript>
  names = ["Fed Jones", "John Smith", "George King", "Wilma Abby"];
  result = arraytoList(names,', ');
  last = listLast(result);
  result = listLen(result) gt 1 ? mid(result, 1, result.lastIndexOf(',')) & ' or' & last : result;
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput>
```

Result:

> Fed Jones, John Smith, George King or Wilma Abby

Comment: Another way of writing `mid(str,1,x)` would be `left(str,x)` :)

Comment: indeed it would be. could have used result.substring(1,x) too.  lots of ways to do the same thing.

Comment: History has shown me that calling underlying Java method does not *always* work for all CF variables unless they are `javacast()`'ed.

Comment: I've never had a problem and I use it a lot.  that isn't to say I never will but haven't yet.  I'd like to see an example.

Comment: @Travis I have had code like this before in my production CF server (ver 8 or 9), and I have had method not found exception emailed to me in onError().  It doesn't happen all the time, or maybe CF9/10 has fixed it.  However, I've avoid calling underlying Java method since. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Was there a value of the "string" in your onError email? I suppose it could happen if the value was numeric. Probably a non-issue here, good food for thought though if you're not testing your data.

Comment: Trying to produce the method not found error. can't so far.  `test = 1; testResult = test.lastIndexOf(',');` still returned -1, not an error.  Were you doing more with the underlying java than simple string methods?

Comment: I was able to get the error. I had to do math on the strings to get CF to convert it to a java double, but doing math on a string then using a string method on it is just silly.  `s = 1; i = "1"; q = i+s; #s# is a #s.getClass().getName()# and #q# is a #q.getClass().getName()#` the result is `1 is a java.lang.String and 2 is a java.lang.Double` trying `q.lastIndexOf("");` does produce the error but I had to go out of my way to make q a numeric value without using javaCast. So, everyone beware! Using methods on wrong data types is bad (duh)!

Comment: @Travis in ColdFusion many types quake like a string, behave like a string, but sometimes it's not a Java string and therefore no such method exception will sometimes be thrown if string methods are just blindly invoked.

Comment: I won't argue that CF tries to make everything behave like a string. If you're certain a string is a real java String I wouldn't consider it "blindly invoked" just like you wouldn't consider javaCast()ing everything as beating it into submission.  There is value added in casting everything to be safe as well as knowing what data types you're using.

Comment: You only need `JavaCast` if you can't be certain you have a required type, which doesn't apply here because if you have done `ArrayToList`, you have a string. Calling `lastIndexOf` on a known string is fine and _not_ blindly invoked.

Comment: @PeterBoughton you're right, in this case the string function should work due to `arrayToList`.  Having said that, I still believe if  certain code can be written with API of CF, I would stay in CF because they tend to be more robust with handling CF datatypes.  From what I remember, I had problem with calling string function on a string that CF thinks is a Date.

Comment: If you want robust/predictable datatypes, use Railo. ;)

Comment: if you're not a regex pro like Peter sometimes using java functions like lastIndexOf for string manipulation is a life saver. for example adding "..." to a string that is too long but not in the middle of a word.